# How to make a new Item in a double chained list?

Tags: c++, list, oop, pointers, templates

I have a double chained list and an item class. I want to implement a function spliced, which does the following

[Splice method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI3MO.png)

The first thing that is required is creating the Handles ap and bn, so i try the following

```
template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::splice(Item<T> *a, Item<T> *b, Item<T> *t)
{
    Item<T> ap()=a->prev;
    Item<T> bn()=b->next;
}
```

Before compiling, my IDE highlights an and bn and says

> Illegal Initializer (only variables can be initialized)

Upon compiling, i get this error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwItq.png)

This is my source code for the **Double linked list** (**you can ignore everything except the splice method, because it was pre-written by our instructors**)

```
#include "DoublyLinkedList.h"

template <class T> DoublyLinkedList<T>::DoublyLinkedList()
{
    h = new Item<T>();
    h->next = h;
    h->prev = h;
}

template <class T> DoublyLinkedList<T>::~DoublyLinkedList()
{
    delete h;
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::splice(Item<T> *a, Item<T> *b, Item<T> *t)
{
    Item<T> ap()=a->prev;
    Item<T> bn()=b->next;
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::head()
{
    return h;// your code
}

template <class T> bool DoublyLinkedList<T>::isEmpty()
{
    return true;// your code
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::first()
{
    return h;// your code
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::last()
{
    return h;// your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::moveAfter(Item<T> *b, Item<T> *a)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::moveToFront(Item<T> *b)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::moveToBack(Item<T> *b)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::removeItem(Item<T> *b)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::popFront()
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::popBack()
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::insertAfter(T new_element, Item<T> *a)
{
    return h;// your code (use "new" to reserve space on the heap for the new Item and make sure to "delete" it at an appropriate position)
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::insertBefore(T new_element, Item<T> *b)
{
    return h;// your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::pushFront(T new_element)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::pushBack(T new_element)
{
    // your code
}

template <class T> Item<T>* DoublyLinkedList<T>::findElement(T new_element)
{
    return h;// your code
}

template <class T> int DoublyLinkedList<T>::getSize()
{
    return 0;// your code
}


// you can ignore the functions below this line
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::bubbleSort()
{
    // not part of this exercise
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::mergeSort()
{
    // not part of this exercise
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::mergeSort_sort(DoublyLinkedList<T> * unsorted_list)
{
    // not part of this exercise
}

template <class T> void DoublyLinkedList<T>::mergeSort_merge(DoublyLinkedList<T>* unsorted_list, DoublyLinkedList<T>* l, DoublyLinkedList<T>* r)
{
    // not part of this exercise
}

#if !__has_include ("aircraft.h")
    template class DoublyLinkedList<int>;
#endif

#if __has_include ("aircraft.h")
    #include "aircraft.h"
    template class DoublyLinkedList<aircraft*>;
#endif
```

**And this is the item.h file**

```
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

template <class T> class Item
{
    public:
        Item();
        Item *prev;
        Item *next;
        T element;
};

template <class T> Item<T>::Item()
{
    prev= this;
    next= this;
}

#endif // ITEM_H
```

Comment: `Item<T> ap()` is a function declaration (takes no parameters and returns a `Item<T>)`, not a variable. If you remove the brackets you'll get initialization of a local variable which, since it isn't used, isn't all that useful.

Comment: `Item<T> *a, Item<T> *b, Item<T> *t)` are not particularly well-named variables. They do not describe what they contain or represent, so I don't know how best to use them to expand my above comment into a worthwhile answer. Consider providing more descriptive names. If these are the names given by your instructor, shame on your instructor.

Comment: It looks like you are asking about a compile-time error. If so, most of this question is needless noise. A [mre] is more effective if you minimize the context needed to parse it (with notes summarizing what you did). You can skip the need for a definition of `DoublyLinkedList<T>` (which you skipped anyway?) by changing the member function to a free function, as in `template <class T> void splice(Item<T> *a, Item<T> *b, Item<T> *t)`. Also consider eliminating the template noise by defining `struct ItemT {};` and changing your function to `void splice(ItemT *a, ItemT *b, ItemT *t)`.

Comment: @user4581301 I would accept the unused variables as part of minimizing the example code. Admittedly, the intent would be clearer if the line after the two attempted variable definitions was something like `// Rest of the function goes here`. *(If this guess is on target, will Fluctuation23 take the hint?)*